# Italicize environment and comment package

Tags: formatting

I used the `comment` package to includecomment/excludecomment an answer environment. This way I can print questions, and then later print the questions and answers together.

The problem I'm trying to solve: the answers look the same as the rest of the text. How do I make them italicized/stick a box around them/make them bold? Can I still use the comment package then to include/exclude them? Or is there perhaps a far better tool for this.

Comment: Please give us something to work with. A little example that shows your use-case. It'll help get answers your way far quicker as well... trust me.

Comment: @Werner understood, next time I will definitely do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On unix(like) systems you can use `texdoc comment`, for example, to read the package documentation. If you read the documentation for the [comment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package then on page 2 you will find:

> Special comments are defined as

```
\specialcomment{〈name〉}{〈before commands〉}{〈after commands〉}
```

> where the second and third arguments are executed before and after each comment block. You can use this for global formatting commands. To keep definitions &c local, you can include \begingroup in the ‘〈before commands〉’ and \endgroup in the ‘〈after commands〉’. ex:

```
\specialcomment{smalltt}{\begingroup\ttfamily\footnotesize}{\endgroup}
```

Consequently, in order to get your comments in italics you can write:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}

\specialcomment{itcomment}{\begingroup\itshape}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
  \begin{itcomment}
    Here is a comment in italics!
  \end{itcomment}
\end{document}
```

and this will produce:

[image]

Comment: It was unreal how fast and complete that answer was. Also sorry for not looking harder for documentation, and thank you!

Comment: @Henry Glad to be of help. I learnt about the `texdoc` command on TeX.SX so there's no need to apologise for not knowing about this:)

Comment: Different Henry here. Come on, you could have spent 10 seconds more for that first paragraph. :) It does not relate to the OS. TeX Live on Windows has the file `texdoc.exe` as well. I do not have MikTeX installed but upon googling, MikTeX has it too.

Comment: @henry Unfortunately I am completely ignorant when it comes to windows:)

Comment: Well, ok. :) I meant that currently the wording makes it seem factually wrong. `texdoc` is not exclusively available on unix-like systems. (although you did not say that verbatim)